# To enable user to choose primefaces datatable filterMatchMode using select menu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a requirement where in my primefaces datatable ,the **filterMatchMode** attribute(like any part of field,whole field) needs to be selected by the user by select menu .To achieve this i have declared a variable in my viewscoped managed bean as **filterCriteria** and set the filterMatchMode attribute as

> filterMatchMode="#{beanName.filterCriteria}"

The bean variable is getting set in the managed bean on submit but the filtering is not happening,i am getting empty message.Also when i remove the keyed in value from filter box the data table is not restored which otherwise must be restored in normal situations. 
I have used and modified the example code given in primefaces showcase [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).The code snippet is as below

```
<h:form id="tblFrm">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="filterOptions"
     value="#{dtFilterView.filterOption}" required="true"
     requiredMessage="You must select an option!">

     <f:selectItem id="hd1" itemLabel="Select" itemValue="#{null}" />
     <f:selectItem id="opt1" itemLabel="Any part of field" itemValue="any" />
     <f:selectItem id="opt2" itemLabel="Whole Field" itemValue="whole" />
     <f:selectItem id="opt3" itemLabel="Start of field" itemValue="strt" />

  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <p:commandButton id="filterSb" value="GO"
     action="#{dtFilterView.filterAction}" update="dtTbl" />


  <p:dataTable var="car" id="dtTbl" value="#{dtFilterView.cars}"
     widgetVar="carsTable"
     emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria"
     filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}">


     <p:column filterBy="#{car.id}" headerText="Id" footerText="contains"
        filterMatchMode="#{dtFilterView.filterCriteria}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
     </p:column>
```

.
.
.

Inside the managed bean the **filterAction** method

```
    public void filterAction()
   {

      if(filterOption.equalsIgnoreCase("any"))
         this.filterCriteria="contains";
      else
         if(filterOption.equalsIgnoreCase("whole"))
            this.filterCriteria="exact";
         else
            if(filterOption.equalsIgnoreCase("strt"))
               this.filterCriteria="startsWith";

   }
```

Where am i going wrong here.Is there any way to achieve this feature.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not forgot getter/setter for filterOption and filterCriteria, it work fine.

xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="filterOptions"
                     value="#{dtFilterView.filterOption}" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="You must select an option!">

        <f:selectItem id="hd1" itemLabel="Select" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItem id="opt1" itemLabel="Any part of field" itemValue="any" />
        <f:selectItem id="opt2" itemLabel="Whole Field" itemValue="whole" />
        <f:selectItem id="opt3" itemLabel="Start of field" itemValue="strt" />

    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton id="filterSb" value="GO"
                     action="#{dtFilterView.filterAction}" 
                     update="dtTbl" />
    <p:dataTable var="car" 
                 value="#{dtFilterView.cars}" 
                 widgetVar="carsTable" 
                 id="dtTbl"
                 emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria" 
                 filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                             onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()" 
                             style="width:150px" 
                             placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>

        <p:column filterBy="#{car.id}" 
                  headerText="Id" 
                  footerText="contains"
                  filterMatchMode="#{dtFilterView.filterCriteria}" >
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{car.year}" 
                  headerText="Year" 
                  footerText="lte" 
                  filterMatchMode="lte">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:spinner onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" 
                           styleClass="year-spinner">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
                </p:spinner>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{car.brand}" 
                  headerText="Brand" 
                  footerText="exact" 
                  filterMatchMode="exact">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" 
                                  itemValue="#{null}" 
                                  noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.brands}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{car.color}" 
                  headerText="Color" 
                  footerText="in" 
                  filterMatchMode="in">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Colors" 
                                      onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" 
                                      panelStyle="width:125px" 
                                      scrollHeight="150">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.colors}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{car.sold}" headerText="Status" 
                  footerText="equals" filterMatchMode="equals">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sold" itemValue="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sale" itemValue="false" />
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car.sold ? 'Sold': 'Sale'}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{car.price}" headerText="Price" 
                  footerText="custom (min)" 
                  filterFunction="#{dtFilterView.filterByPrice}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.price}">
                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

managedbean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dtFilterView")
@ViewScoped
public class FilterView implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars;

    private List<Car> filteredCars;

    private String filterOption;

    private String filterCriteria;

    @ManagedProperty("#{carService}")
    private CarService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars = service.createCars(10);
    }

    public boolean filterByPrice(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
        String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
        if (filterText == null || filterText.equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return ((Comparable) value).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(filterText)) > 0;
    }

    public List<String> getBrands() {
        return service.getBrands();
    }

    public List<String> getColors() {
        return service.getColors();
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public List<Car> getFilteredCars() {
        return filteredCars;
    }

    public void setFilteredCars(List<Car> filteredCars) {
        this.filteredCars = filteredCars;
    }

    public void setService(CarService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getFilterOption() {
        return filterOption;
    }

    public void setFilterOption(String filterOption) {
        this.filterOption = filterOption;
    }

    public String getFilterCriteria() {
        return filterCriteria;
    }

    public void setFilterCriteria(String filterCriteria) {
        this.filterCriteria = filterCriteria;
    }

    public void filterAction() {

        if (filterOption.equalsIgnoreCase("any")) {
            this.filterCriteria = "contains";
        } else if (filterOption.equalsIgnoreCase("whole")) {
            this.filterCriteria = "exact";
        } else if (filterOption.equalsIgnoreCase("strt")) {
            this.filterCriteria = "startsWith";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ,thanks you made my day!!!.But still i am not able to find out where i went wrong :)